# Is it possible to write a macro that counts items and generates an enum?

Tags: macros, rust

I want something like this:

```
define_enum_and_all_variants! ( Test {
    One, Two, Three
});
```

to produce:

```
enum Test {
  One, Two, Three
}
const ALL_VARIANTS: [Test; 3] = [One, Two, Three];
```

the problem here is `3`, I can write something like this:

```
macro_rules! define_enum_and_all_variants {
    ($Name:ident { $($Variant:ident),* }) =>
    {
        #[derive(Debug)]
        enum $Name {
            $($Variant),*,
        }
        #[allow(dead_code)]
        const ALL_VARIANTS: [$Name; 3] = [$($Name::$Variant),*];
    }
}
```

but how to calculate number of elements in `enum`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't really answer the question, but only because you have a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Instead of writing

```
const ALL: [u32; 3] = [1, 2, 3];
```

you could write

```
const ALL: &'static [u32] = &[1, 2, 3];
```

Thus your macro should be

```
const ALL_VARIANTS: &'static [$Name] = &[$($Name::$Variant),*];
```

---

To answer the other question ("how to count with macros"): it's a simple head-tail-kind-of-algorithm:

```
macro_rules! count {
    ($head:ident $(, $tail:ident)*) => {  1 + count!($($tail),*) };
    () => { 0 };
}

println!("{}", count!());  // 0
println!("{}", count!(A)); // 1
println!("{}", count!(A, B, C, D)); // 4
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem for me was not to write `count!` macro, but how to combine analog of your `count!` macro and main macro that generate `enum`. But this not important, because of missed `&[]` solution.